# Proving Cavalieri's Two-Dimensional Theorem

Tags: calculus, geometry, solution-verification, area

I just wanted to check that my proof of the following theorem is correct.

*Theorem:*

If two plane regions can be arranged to lie over the same interval of the $x$-axis in such a way that they have identical vertical cross sections at every point, then the regions have the same area.

The problem says we may assume that each region is bounded above and below by the graphs of continuous functions.

*Proof:*

Consider two plane regions $A$ and $B$. Assume $A$ is bounded above by the continuous function $f(x)$ for all $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ and bounded below by the continuous function $g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Similarly, assume $B$ is bounded above by the continuous function $h(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and bounded below by the continuous function $k(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Then by definition we have that since $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, $f(x)-g(x)$ is the length of the cross section of $A$ for any $x\in[a,b]$. Likewise, since $h(x)\geq k(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, $h(x)-k(x)$ is the length of the cross section of $B$ for any $x\in[a,b].$

Note by assumption the two plane regions have identical vertical cross sections at every point, thus $$f(x)-g(x)=h(x)-k(x) \space \space \space \text{for all $x\in[a,b]$}\implies\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)dx=\int_a^b\left(h(x)-k(x)\right)dx$$

where $\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)dx$ is the area of the region between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ from $a$ to $b$, and $\int_a^b\left(h(x)-k(x)\right)dx$ is the area of the region between $h(x)$ and $k(x)$ from $a$ to $b$.

Hence since $\text{area}(A)=\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)dx$ and $\text{area}(B)=\int_a^b\left(h(x)-k(x)\right)dx$, we have $\text{area}(A)=\text{area}(B)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You don't need them (i.e. - the cross sections)  to be *identical*. They can be translates of each other. The crucial thing is that they have the same lengths.